# NextJS OAuth2 authentication server side without express

Tags: authentication, google-oauth, next.js

I would like to add OAuth2 authentication (I will start with Google) to my NextJS app without using an extra service like Auth0.

This would be possible with PassportJS, but then I need to add Express as a custom server and I will loose some advantages of NextJS.

Next has middleware support but for only for connect: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares

I don't want a client only solution. I prefer server side with http-only cookies.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** You can now use this: https://next-auth.js.org/

**Old answer:**
I seems that I can use PassportJS with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect
Next-connect allows middleware similar to Express.
Here is an example of using PassportJS: https://github.com/hoangvvo/nextjs-mongodb-app